# How should dependent javascript include be handled in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, pycharm

I have a Flask app.  I am using the latest PyCharm.  I am creating a couple of Typescript modules for this app.  I have the Typescript code in a folder under the project root:

```
my_project/
    app/
        static/
            js/
                utilities.js
                utilities.map
        ...
    TypescriptSources/
        Messages/
            messages.ts
            tsconfig.json
        Utilities/
            tsconfig.json
            utilities.js
            utilities.js.map
            utilities.ts
```

`messages.ts` needs to include `utilities.js`, as in:

```
import {Utilities} from './utilities.js'

export class Messages {...}
```

Except `'./utilities.js'` is not the correct path for the TS "source" file but it will be when the compile process moves the resulting javascript into the `app/static/js` folder.

I am very new to Typescript and `tsconfig.json` files.  How should I manage dependent javasscript includes?

**Edit**
I was missing the fact that i should be maintaining "relative paths" for the typescript results.

Comment: That's the completely wrong import path? Should be `../Utilities/utilities`? And why do you have the same compiled js output in two different places? And compilation should preserve the directory structure? Why do you mention what *IDE you are using*? What relevance does that have? There's a lot of unknowns here based on no more than you've posted, and I'm not the DV but this whole thing smells kinda funky....

Comment: Totally dig it.  My question is: should I use the "source code" path or the "app/static/js" path?  After Typescript does the compile and copies the resulting code into the "js" folder the "./utilities.js" path would be fine but the thing will not compile because "./utilities.js" is not in the Messages source folder.

Comment: The compiled output should preserve the directory structure so that the same *relative path* import of `../Utilities/utilities` works either way. You would have `TypescriptSources/Utilities/utilities.ts` be compiled out to `static/js/Utilities/utilities.js` and `TypescriptSources/Messages/messages.ts` should be compiled out to `static/js/Messages/messages.js` and the relative import from one to the other is the same either way. Honestly none of this should matter because you should probably use a bundler like rollup or vite to compile *all* your TS files to a *single* JS file.

Comment: Thank you.  the relative paths should be the same.  I was not maintaining that in the tsconfig files.